# Checkmarking custom tableView cells and section headers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to allow a tableView to automatically checkmark all custom row cells in a section when a custom section header is tapped? I haven't seen any tutorials that cover this, and was wondering if it's at all possible? How would I go about tracking each row and section, so I can modify string values in a string array that has the same number of elements as there are rows in the table?

Answer (score 0):

In this case (below) I just put an accessory type on the cell clicked and append the element selected on a list of selected items. You could append all elements of a list when something is pressed using gesture handling.

This is my code:

```
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return }

    if cell.accessoryType == .none {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        selectedItems.append(items[indexPath.row])
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        if let text = cell.textLabel?.text,
            let index = selectedItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == text}) {
            selectedItems.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            print("Error removing selected item from array.")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps in some way. Regards!